# MASM dll memory allocation

Tags: memory, assembly, masm, heapalloc

I need help with my MASM dll. I'm counting elements in array then I want to allocate memory for another array, in C I'm using vector.
I  tried to use:

```
invoe GetProcessHeap
invoke HeapAlloc, eax, HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE + HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, <size>
```

or

```
invoke GlobalAlloc, GMEM_ZEROINIT, <size>
mov tab, eax
```

but I'm getting errors `undefined symbol : GetProcessHeap` `undefined symbol : HeapAlloc`

I'm using this library in C# application.
Can you show me example how can I dynamically allocate memory?

Comment: You compiled your assembly code to a dll, and you're trying to use that dll from a C# application? Or are you trying to invoke C functions from your assembly code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link against the appropriate library. If you look at [the MSDN page for `HeapAlloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366597%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you'll see that it's located in `kernel32.dll`.

Assuming that you're using MASM32 there should be a `kernel32.inc` (for the procedure prototype) and `kernel32.lib` (for linking) included with your MASM32 installation. So you need to add the following lines to your assembly file:

```
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
```

If you don't have a `kernel32.lib` file it gets a bit more complicated, but it's still doable by using `LoadLibrary` to load `kernel32.dll` and then getting the address of the `HeapAlloc` function with `GetProcAddress`.